# Absolute position and wrong z-index

Tags: css, z-index, css-position

**Plot Explanation:** There's a bird that should collect it's legs before flying. Bird's body, legs and eye are `background-image`s of separate `div`s. I used jQuery's animate method to change legs position and put them inside the bird's body.

**Problem:** Instead of legs going under the bird's body, they stay above it.

**Question:** What am I doing wrong that makes bird's legs not going under it?

**Images:**

1. [image: Before animation]
2. [image: After Animation]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="gonji">
    <div class="legs"></div>
    <div class="body">
        <div class="eye"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#gonji { width: 80px; height: 55px; position: relative; }
#gonji .body { width: 80px; height: 55px; background: url('../gonji/gonji.png') no-repeat scroll center center transparent; z-index: 998; }
#gonji .eye { width: 5px; height: 4px; background: url('../gonji/gonji_eye.png') no-repeat scroll center center transparent; position: absolute; top: 13px; left: 30px; z-index: 999; }
#gonji .legs{ width: 9px; height: 17px; background: url('../gonji/gonji_legs.png') no-repeat scroll center center transparent; position: absolute; top: 35px; left: 30px; z-index: 1 }
```

**JS:**

```
var $gonjiLegs = $("#gonji").find(".legs");
var gonjiOrigLegsPos = $gonjiLegs.position();
$gonjiLegs.animate({ 'top': gonjiOrigLegsPos.top - 17 }, 'fast');
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're missing a `position` property on `#gonji .body` .. z-index only works on positioned elements

Try adding `position: relative;`

Answer (score 2):

You must change the `z-index`.

`z-index:-1;` on `.feet`.

You can as well keep the same position, and just change between `.hide()` and `.show()`.

Comment: I've tried `z-index:-1` and it works, but I'm afraid using `-1` for z-index causes another problem when more elements stay on each other.

Comment: What's the use of `hide()`? It's only matter of coming up and down!

Comment: What I meant that instead of making the legs come up and down, you can hide them by default, `display:none;`, then you can show them by jquery `.show()`.

Comment: Thanks but I want them to go up and down! :D

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
#gonji { width: 80px; height: 55px; position: relative; }
#gonji .body { width: 80px; height: 55px; background:red; z-index: 998; }
#gonji .eye { width: 5px; height: 4px; background:blue; position: absolute; top: 13px; left: 30px; z-  index: 999; }
#gonji .feet { width: 9px; height: 17px; background:black; position: absolute; top: 55px; left: 30px; }
```

**JS**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(callMe,1000);
 });

function callMe(){
var $gonjiFeet = $("#gonji").find(".feet");
var gonjiOrigFeetPos = $gonjiFeet.position();
$gonjiFeet.css('z-index','-1').animate({ 'top': gonjiOrigFeetPos.top - 20 }, 'fast');
$gonjiFeet.animate({ 'top': '55' }, 'fast');
}
```